# CSS Transitions on list item background

Tags: css, css-transitions

I use CSS transitions fairly regularly and for some reason I cannot get them to work on a simple unordered list. I created a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/79NhC/

On the list item, I have the following css:

```
#servicesBox li {
    border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee; 
    padding:10px 0 10px 10px;  
    webkit-transition: background 0.2s; 
    moz-transition: background 0.2s; 
    ms-transition: background 0.2s; 
    o-transition: background 0.2s; 
    transition: background 0.2s; 
}​
```

For some reason, when a user hovers over the list item, the background does not gracefully fade in. Any reason why? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a `-` before all of your browser-specific transition declarations.

So, like this:

```
#servicesBox li
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: background 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: this works well in the jsfiddle, but for some reason it does not work in my file. Other transitions on my page are working fine. ANything else that could cause a transition to not function properly?

Comment: The old CSS file could be cached, or another property is overwriting it.  Without seeing the code, there could be any number of reasons why it works in the fiddle and not on your site.

Comment: You can take a peak here:  http://bajdesign.com/fs/index.php   the area not working is the list of four in the top right

Comment: looks like the problem is that on hover, I am using a background image, not color. I figured the 'background' property would cover images as well

Comment: in the jsfiddle, I used a background-color, which is why it worked great

Comment: You may also want to try applying the transition properties to the `#servicesBox li:hover` definition, instead of `#servicesBox li`

Comment: The problem is that  you can't use transition on background-image, see the w3c list of animatable properties. That said, I am looking for a workaround

Comment: While W3C may not define background image as an animatable property, the [browser-specific definitions](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/) may.  Instead of `transition: color...`, use `transition: background...`.  [Proof-of-concept](http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/fading-button-background-images-with-css3-transitions/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13076/discussion-between-jchase11-and-mrslayer)

Comment: I ended up giving a background image to the entire UL and then a background of white to the list items and transparent on hover. That gave me the results I needed!